# Сочетание строки с числом - ошибка

Tags: python

У меня есть код. С виду идентичный, но я получаю ошибку. Кто может сказать почему?
Даже, если я в возрасте введу float, то ошибки не будет. А в процентах она есть.

Без ошибки:

```
age = input("Введите Ваш возраст: ")
print("Ваш возраст: " + age + " лет")
```

С ошибкой:

```
a1 = 532
a2 = 2063
target = a1 / a2 * 100
print(target + "%")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `input` возвращает строку.

> Даже, если я в возрасте введу float

В `age` все равно будет строка.

Во втором примере `target` имеет тип `float`. А `float` со строкой без явного преобразования складывать нельзя.

`print(str(target) + '%')` - так заработает.